# In the reccord replace null values by one value IN ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to replace null value by the value in Oracle SQL :

ACTUAL (1 records)

```
UNSPECIFIED FR  
PI_AUTOR_MIN5000_OPNAT  FR  102000
PI_AUTOR_MIN5000_OPNAT  FR  (null)
PI_AUTOR_MIN5000_OPNAT  FR  (null)
```

FUTUR

```
UNSPECIFIED FR  
PI_AUTOR_MIN5000_OPNAT  FR  102000
PI_AUTOR_MIN5000_OPNAT  FR  102000
PI_AUTOR_MIN5000_OPNAT  FR  102000
```

Comment: Always the same value? `COALESCE(FR, 102000)`.

Comment: Not the same value, the value changes with each record here i showed 1 record.

Comment: Then your the sample data should have different values, to better illustrate the problem.

Comment: Do you think you will always replace null with `one` not null values ? What if there are multiple not null values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a correlated subquery:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable t1
SET col2 = (SELECT MAX(t2.col2) FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.col1 = t1.col1);
```

This assumes that `col1` holds the value `PI_AUTOR_MIN5000_OPNAT  FR` and `col2` holds `102000` or it holds `NULL`.

If instead you want to *view* your data with the `NULL` values filled in, then use:

```sql
SELECT col1, MAX(col2) OVER (PARTITION BY col1) col2
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Hello Tim, is in the select statement .
I can make a subquery ?

Comment: @Vanessa2509 Check the updated answer for one approach.

Comment: Tim, SELECT col1, MAX(col2) OVER (PARTITION BY col1) col2
FROM yourTable;

It's ok ! THANKS !!